# Trying to fire a function inside an angular controller after bootstrap modal is dismissed

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, angular-controller

I'm basically trying to figure out how to do a certain event listener within an angular controller. More specifically, when a bootstrap modal is dismissed I would like to fire a function within the angular controller. In jquery you can normally do something like:

```
$(.some-class).on('click', function() {
   // do something
});
```

What i have is a side navigation with images as buttons. I have gray buttons for when they're inactive and red buttons when they're active. Each button launches a bootstrap modal.

I'm using:

```
<a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#overview" ng-click="launchOverview()">
    <img ng-src="{{ sideNavActive.overviewSrc }}" /><br />
  </a>
```

and I have an object in my controller:

```
$scope.sideNavActive = {
        "overviewSrc": "img/side-nav/tab-overview-off.png",
        "detailsSrc": "img/side-nav/tab-details-off.png",
        "contactSrc": "img/side-nav/tab-contact-off.png"
}
```

When the user clicks one of the side-nav buttons i have an ng-click function that changes the button to "img/...-on.png" so the button turns red (active). When the user clicks another side-nav button it turns that button red and the rest gray.

What I'm trying to do is when the user clicks in the faded area around the modal to dismiss it, i also want the buttons to all reset to gray. According to the bootstrap documentation I should be able to fire a function on the 'hidden.bs.modal' event but I can't get it to work in my angular controller. I have the following function where '#overview' is my id for my modal.

```
$('#overview').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
        console.log('function fired!!!!!');
        $scope.sideNavActive = {
          "overviewSrc": "img/side-nav/tab-overview-off.png",
          "detailsSrc": "img/side-nav/tab-details-off.png",
          "contactSrc": "img/side-nav/tab-contact-off.png"
        }
      })
```

However, this function doesn't fire when the modal is dismissed and I can't figure out why.

One thing I've done to see if the function is actually listening is changed it to:

```
$('body').on('click', function() {
  // function code here
}
```

and it works. It fires whenever I click anywhere since it's listening on the 'body' element. So I know it's listening but for some reason the 'hidden.bs.modal' event isn't working.

Comment: dont mix jquery with angular

Comment: @ThanhTùng How can I convert it to angular then? I've done: 

`angular.element('#overview').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
        console.log('function fired!!!!!');
        $scope.sideNavActive = {
          "overviewSrc": "img/side-nav/tab-overview-off.png",
          "detailsSrc": "img/side-nav/tab-details-off.png",
          "contactSrc": "img/side-nav/tab-contact-off.png"
        }
      })`

and it still didn't work.

Comment: you try use `$scope.launchOverview = function(){}`

Answer (score 1):

I would use the angular-ui-bootstrap modal if you're not already: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal. There is a callback function on the modal instance that is executed when the modal is dismissed:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (someObj) {
      // success 
    }, function () {
      // this code will be executed when the modal is dismissed
      console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to fire a function in an angular controller when modal is dismissed.

```
angular.element(document).find('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
  // do something
  console.log('function fired');
});
```